# Javascript message

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox

I am having some problems fixing my JS code.
In the snippet code you can see my program,

Now click the first checkbox. A message appears at the bottem, as soon as I type a number in it the message should dissapear and the textbox should not disable ...

When I click a second checkbox the message should append to the previous, but it just overwrites... and then with the same values as the previous one ...

Can anyone give me some idea's about that? Should be something wrong in the test function ...

Thank you in advance.

```js
// JavaScript source code


function test(el)
{
    divOutput = document.getElementById("msgbox2");
    strValideer = "<ul>";
    var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'))
    if (el.checked === true ) {
        txt.disabled = false;
        if(txt.value==="")
        {
            strValideer += "<li><b>" + txt.name + ": </b>verplicht veld</li>";
        }
        }
    else if (el.checked === false)
    {
        txt.disabled = true;
      return;

    }

    strValideer += "</ul>";
    divOutput.innerHTML = strValideer;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
                <legend>Bestel gegevens</legend>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span7" id="houtsoorten">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    bangkirai
                                    <input id="chkbangkirai" type="checkbox" onchange="test(this)" >
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txtbangkirai" name="bangkirai" placeholder="aantal" disabled oninput="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">stuks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    beukenhout
                                    <input id="chkbeukenhout" type="checkbox" onchange="test(this)">
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txtbeukenhout" name="beukenhout" placeholder="aantal" disabled oninupt="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">stuks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    dennenhout
                                    <input id="chkdennenhout" type="checkbox" onchange="test(this)">
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txtdennenhout" name="dennenhout" placeholder="aantal" disabled oninput="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">stuks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    eikenhout
                                    <input id="chkeikenhout" type="checkbox" onclick="test(this)">
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txteikenhout" name="eikenhout" placeholder="aantal" disabled oninput="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">stuks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    kastanjehout
                                    <input id="chkkastanjehout" type="checkbox" onchange="test(this)">
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txtkastanjehout" name="kastanjehout" placeholder="aantal" disabled oninput="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">stuks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    lindehout
                                    <input id="chklindehout" type="checkbox" onchange="test(this)">
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txtlindehout" name="lindehout" placeholder="aantal" disabled oninput="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">stuks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    notenhout
                                    <input id="chknotenhout" type="checkbox" onchange="test(this)">
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append inline">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txtnotenhout" name="notenhout" placeholder="aantal" disabled oninput="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">stuks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    rubberhout
                                    <input id="chkrubberhout" type="checkbox" onchange="test(this)">
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append inline">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txtrubberhout" name="rubberhout" placeholder="aantal" disabled oninput="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">stuks</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    Cederhout
                                    <input id="chkCederhout" type="checkbox" onchange="test(this)">
                                </label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append inline">
                                        <input class="inpbox input-mini" type="text" id="txtCederhout" name="Cederhout" placeholder="kg" disabled oninput="test(this)">
                                        <span class="add-on">kg</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">betalingswijze</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <label class="radio">
                                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="visa" value="visa">
                                        visa
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio">
                                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="overschrijving" value="overschrijving">
                                        overschrijving
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio">
                                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="cash" value="cash">
                                        cash
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">opmerkingen:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea rows="5" placeholder="opmerkingen"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span4 valid">
                            <div id="msgbox2" class="alert alert-error" style="display: block;">validatie bestelgegevens verschijnt hier
                        </div>
                        <div class="span1"><!--lege kolom--></div>
                        <!--einde row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--einde container-->
                  </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: Don't just copy & paste your whole code in here.  Give us the minimum code required to show us what your problem is - read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Done, sorry sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the children first it has nodes or not. Check the function it will work now

```
var list = [];
function test(el) {
    divOutput = document.getElementById("msgbox2");
    strValideer = "<ul>";
    var txt = document.getElementById(el.id.replace('chk', 'txt'));
    if (el.checked === true) {
        txt.disabled = false;
        if (txt.value === "") {
            list.push(txt.name);
        }
    }
    else if (el.checked === false) {
        txt.disabled = true;
        list.splice(list.indexOf(txt.name), 1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        strValideer += "<li><b>" + list[i] + ": </b>verplicht veld</li>";
    }
    strValideer += "</ul>";
    divOutput.innerHTML = strValideer;
}
```

Comment: I get what you mean, but now the message still appears or does not disappear when you enter a value to a textbox. Each checkbox checked with no value in the textbox should show a message, the rest not

Comment: @VanonckelenDieter while uncheck you need to remove that right ?

Comment: when you uncheck or there is a value in the textbox, the message should remove for that textbox / checkbox

Comment: @VanonckelenDieter please check the updated answer it will remove list on uncheck and please vote up and check the accepted answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Did the most i was troubling with, not 100% but ill try find it myself. Thank you Praveen Kumar